# How to access Constructor of Parent class in C++ with parent class having a pure virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, virtual-functions

I am trying to create  Circle and Rectangle from Class Shape. I want y to be assigned pi if I call Shape() constructor with a parameter (from circle class). Since Shape has a purely virtual function the compiler is showing error. How can I overcome this error. And why is default parameter running correctly then?
Also I tried this->Shape(0) from Circle class. Compiler is saying "Invalid use of this"

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Shape
{public:
double x,y;

   Shape()
   {x=0;y=0;}

   Shape(int p,int t=3.14159)
   {x=p;y=t;}

   virtual void display_area()=0;
   virtual void get_data()=0;
};



class Circle: public Shape
{public:

    Circle()
    {Shape(0);}    //ERROR HERE

    void get_data()
    {cout<<"\nRadius: ";cin>>x;}

    void display_area()
    {cout<<"\nArea: "<<y*x*x;}
};
```

Comment: No wonders you can't fix your code if it is such badly formatted. Rule #1: format your code properly!

Comment: Why is your code so poorly formatted? How can you read this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

base classes are always initialized before the constructor's block runs, so you do it in the constructor's [member initialization list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)..

I also fixed another bug in your code.... You are doing some narrowing conversions, which wouldn't work as you want...

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Shape
{
public:
    double x,y;

Shape()
{  
     x=0;
     y=0;
}

Shape(double p, double t=3.14159)   //changed from Shape(int p, int t=3.14159)
{  
     x=p;
     y=t;
}

virtual void display_area()=0;

virtual void get_data()=0;
};

class Circle: public Shape
{
public:
    Circle() : Shape(0)
{  /*Shape(0); */ }    //Not HERE

void get_data()
{   
     cout<<"\nRadius: ";
     cin>>x;
}

void display_area()
{
     cout<<"\nArea: "<<y*x*x;}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

To call the base constructor you need to use the `member initialization list`.

Change:

```
Circle()
{
    Shape(0);
}    //ERROR HERE
```

To

```
Circle() : Shape(0)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks Jose The code worked but its showing integers instead of decimals

Comment: Shape(0) is calling the second constructor (which accepts two ints, not to floats or doubles). Since the first int is set to 0, and t is set to 3 * 0 = 0. Perhaps you may want to change the second constructor to accept doubles.